# Can Ferengis grow hair?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

Ferengis always appear hairless. Can they grow hair (but merely choose not to), or are they physically incapable of doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

According to *Deep Space Nine* executive producer Ira Behr, as recounted in the *Deep Space Nine Companion*:

> Responds Behr, “Robert had this feeling that given the way Ferengi look, the style of
> body with big heads and ears and little eyes and no hair, that they
> would live in a moist climate.”
>
> <sub>*Deep Space Nine Companion*</sub>

This would definitely seem to confirm that they don’t have any hair as an innate quality due to having evolved on a wet planet, not by choice.

Comment: I disagree. That quote doesn't say whether "no hair", in-universe, is prescriptive or descriptive. There could be a Ferengi custom that growing hair makes you a weakling, so they all make sure to shave their heads. Or it's simply *more convenient* to go hairless when living in a moist climate.

Comment: @Randal’Thor - Well, the big ears and little eyes are presumably not prescriptive. I read the whole quote as one part, referring to intrinsic characteristics of the Ferengi.

Answer (score 9):

Grand Nagus Zek has ear hair. Does that count?

[image]

Comment: I don’t think that’s really what the question was asking.... It was more about whether they had hair on their heads.

Comment: @Adamant the OP used the term 'hairless', not 'bald'. As the question is phrased, I think this is the right answer, it proves the Ferengi *can* 'grow hair'.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the answer above that implies by design physiology that the Ferengi are without hair *a priori*, the following book I read some years ago goes some way to explain (from a fashion point of view) why some Ferengi will not even have hair in the ears and nostrils. In short, they purchase a *Gweemo Lobemaster*

[Star Trek \ DS9: Legends of the Ferengi](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kxlG2bJV6u4C&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=ferengi%20hair&source=bl&ots=ssH5HWc2Ib&sig=hfOPbPikZPX_4NvHqE_uigfAdwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5wpOip7fRAhXIthoKHXXtBSgQ6AEIRTAL#v=onepage&q=ferengi%20hair&f=false)